# Loop on array of arrays - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting an array of arrays from a service and i want to display case [0] and [1] on each iteration, but when I do that i get an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

```
      <ng-container
                *ngFor="let done of this.launch.doneAreas; index as i">
                <div class="display-result">
                  Case n° {{ i + 1 }} => ({{ done[i][0] }},{{ done[i][1] }})
                </div>
      </ng-container>
```

The array is defined like this in the service:

```
  doneAreas: any[][] = [];
```

and I'm pushing values by pushing an array of numbers into it. coords beeing an array of two numbers.

```
  this.doneAreas.push(this.coords);
```

Here's an example of the array i want to display when I console.log it.

0: (2) [3, 3]

1: (2) [3, 4]

2: (2) [4, 4]

3: Array(2)
0: 4
1: 3
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Thanks

Comment: What is the format of this.coords?

Comment: `done` is already an object of the first array so you don't need the index to access the data of the second array: `done[0]` and `done[1]`

Comment: coords is defined like this => coords: [number, number] = [0, 0];

Comment: @Nick but how to access the differents cells ? i would like to use [0] and [1] separately

Comment: oh i got it, didn't need the done[i] to get the datas, just done. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a dynamic object {x: number, y: number}. If you use that in a list you can ensure both should be present.

Your issue is that done already is an object and you are trying to get the index of an array that is not present.

```
doneAreas: {x: number, y: number}[] = [];
```

```
this.doneAreas.push({this.coords.x, this.coords.y);
```

```
<ng-container
          *ngFor="let done of this.launch.doneAreas; index as i">
          <div class="display-result">
            Case n° {{ i + 1 }} => ({{ done.x }},{{ done.y }})
          </div>
</ng-container>
```

If you want to keep the code as it is you should just remove [I]:

```
      <ng-container
                *ngFor="let done of this.launch.doneAreas; index as i">
                <div class="display-result">
                  Case n° {{ i + 1 }} => ({{ done[0] }},{{ done[1] }})
                </div>
      </ng-container>
```